# Delays in CC payment processing by paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, recurring-billing

I am working on a subscription system that integrates payments through CC and paypal account, the problem happens in delay in activating the recurring profile of subscribers paying through CC.

I am using "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile" API call for creating recurring profile. Initially I relied solely on IPN messages for payment confirmation, but there are delays in receiving these sometimes for few hours, for some users, but since IPN messages are only initiated with changes made in merchant's account, i believe the transfer of money could take time, and thus the delay.

I then thought of momentarily activating the profile based on instant responses from "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile" and then the account is deactivated if we subsequently receive a IPN messages of txn_type payment skipped. My question is how most sites implement instant activating recurring payments using paypal api and is SUCCESS response from "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile" is reliable to indicate that payment has happened?

Comment: I got the same problem.. did you managed to find a solution?